# SVN folder deletion

Tags: svn

I want to know how can we delete folder/project from svn repository in windows environment. I have created folders and projects using SVN administration but there is no option of remove/delete here.

Thanks

Comment: which svn client your using?

Comment: was the answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample:

```
svn delete http://www.yourrepository.com/svn/folder --message "Deleting"
```

And if you use TortoiseSVN: [Deleting, Moving and Renaming](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html)

Answer (score 0):

There will be no option to delete folders from admin panel,instead you can try from `svn client` like `Rapid SVN`,

Right Click on folder in right tab then there will be option called 'Delete' and check the 'Force Remove' check box and click on 'Ok' button.